# Deeplinking complex route in Here WeGo

Tags: here-api

For our use case, we need a turn-by-turn navigation on a mobile device but using a custom route.
Please let me know if the following usage scenario is possible:
Given an array of points (lat/long) that the route needs to pass through, get a route using CalculateRoute.
Create a deeplink for HERE WeGo (e.g. iOS) using the sequence of waypoints obtained in step #1
Navigate turn by turn in HERE WeGo along the route
So far I was successful in #1 but could not create a deeplink with the same route for HERE WeGo. When I create a link, the app simplifies the route to only include origin and destination points and omits all "via" points.

Would appreciate advice on this.

Comment: In general passing the waypoints one after the other should open the route with the intermediate points (at least on wego.here.com) , not so sure if this work out of the box in HERE WE Go https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/topics/share-route.html

Answer (score 0):

In general passing the waypoints one after the other should open the route with the intermediate points (at least on wego.here.com) , not so sure if this work out of the box in HERE WE Go https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/dev_guide/topics/share-route.html